# How do I cause a squid proxy to log all requests?

Tags: proxy, squid

We have a Squid proxy server for testing.  We are trying to verify that traffic is passing through it, but by default access.log is only showing TCP_DENIED and TCP_MISS so we don't know if messages are going through the proxy or not by tailing the log.  Is it possible to configure Squid to log all HTTP requests that pass through it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is logging all requests.

`TCP_MISS` means that it did not load the response from a cache. See [Squid Log Files](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidLogs#access.log) for a listing of all tag types.

> These tags are optional and describe whether the response was loaded from cache, network, or otherwise:
>
> **`HIT`** The response object delivered was the local cache object.
>
> **`MEM`** Additional tag indicating the response object came from memory cache, avoiding disk accesses. Only seen on `HIT` responses.
>
> **`MISS`** The response object delivered was the network response object.
>
> **`DENIED`** The request was denied by access controls.
>
> **`NOFETCH`** A ICP specific type. Indicating service is alive, but not to be used for this request. Sent during `-Y` startup, or during frequent failures, a cache in hit only mode will return either `UDP_HIT` or `UDP_MISS_NOFETCH`. Neighbours will thus only fetch hits.

Refresh a page with a log of static images in a browser that is going through the proxy and you will likely see a lot of `TCP_IMS_HIT` which means the request was on the HTTP port (usually 3128), the client sent a revalidation (conditional) request and the response object delivered was the local cache object.